# building a jquery mobile to an apk without using phonegap build

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

Is there a way one can build an android app from jquery mobile without using phonegap build

```
Phonegap build requires a licence key for ios.
```

Comment: Yes you can build a Cordova App with jQuery mobile and generate an apk-file with an IDE like Android Studio or Visual Studio. Not quite sure if this what you want to know...

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloud build or local build(using eclipse/android sdk) to build APK file. For building IPA, key(p12+provisioning profile) is compulsory for clould as well as local build(Mac require for building IPA).